# php postgres UPDATE: check for success

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm attempting to UPDATE my postgres table on Heroku and have been blocked by the eccentricity of the UPDATE statement.

My initial guess was to say:

```
$query = pg_query($someDB, $updateQuery);
```

and then check if it is false, but to no avail. Here's the troublesome snippet:

```
$update_query = "UPDATE jellybeans SET $form[1]=$data[1], $form[2]=$data[2] WHERE $form[0]='$data[0]'";
echo 'attempting update: ' . $update_query . '<br>';
$update = pg_query($connect, $update_query);
echo "Rows updated: ", pg_affected_rows($update);
//if update failed, push to the table
```

How does one check on statements like INSERTS, DELETES, and the like? I'm surprised affected_rows doesn't return anything meaningful. Much appreciated.

**EDIT: ** Using a SELECT query first yielded the best result:

```
$exists_query = "SELECT * FROM jellybeans WHERE $form[0]='$data[0]'";
$exists = pg_query($connect, $exists_query);
                        if($row = pg_fetch_row($exists)){
                                $update_query = "UPDATE jellybeans SET $form[1]=$data[1], $form[2]=$data[2] WHERE $form[0]='$data[0]'  RETURNING *";
                                echo '<br>' . 'Attempting: ' . $update_query;
                                $update = pg_query($connect, $update_query);
                        }else{
                                $insert_query = "INSERT INTO jellybeans VALUES('$data[0]', $data[1], $data[2])";
                                echo '<br>' . 'Attempting: ' . $insert_query;
                                $insert = pg_query($connect, $insert_query);
                                pg_free_result($insert); 

                        }
                        pg_free_result($exists);
                        pg_free_result($update);
```

From there a simple $row = pg_fetch_row($exists) gives a reliable existence check. In the future, it would probably be best to add an IF FOUND check into the query itself.

Comment: `pg_affected_rows()` doesn't return anything meaningful. What does it return? share an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of knowing is to get the updated rows:

```
UPDATE ... WHERE condition RETURNING *;
```

This will return the set of rows updated, just count the number of results.

Comment: I get a weird result back where an UPDATE that doesn't alter any rows, returns > 0 with this $affected_rows = count(pg_query($connect, $update_query));

Comment: Update your question with that example, I am confident we'll sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."ChangePassword"(
    IN id int,
    IN pwd text,
    OUT affectedrows int)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    UPDATE "UserProfile" SET "Password" = pwd WHERE "Id" = id;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS affectedrows := ROW_COUNT;

END
$BODY$;
```

After execution of the stored procedure in below way, it will return the affected row count(s), if any.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Why are you even using pg_* functions? Have you considered using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead? You'd probably have more luck with [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: PDO is only useful when using different databases. It's a PITA when working with PostgreSQL, everything takes more code and you get less functionality.

Comment: No it isn't. It's object oriented and you don't have to pass db connection as argument all the time, also it has better placeholders. Also, even if I use only one database in aproject, I'd rather be able to use the same class to work with databases in other projects that use different databases -- common interfaces rule.

Comment: PDO offers less performances than native driver in addition to offer less features.